# Index file of a site is stuck online, how to wipe it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sftp

I've recently bought a domain and hosting; after successfully managed to connect via SFTP and upload *html/css/js* files, I noticed that I wasn't getting any updates on the site.
I tried to delete the cache, change the browser, the device and even wipe all the files via SFTP, the fact is that is still loading the old index file.

What am I doing wrong that the site is still up?

Comment: You should contact your hosting provider for support. Maybe there is a problem with your configuration, or with the instructions that they gave you - both of which we can't fix and they can. As such this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterB Thank you for the answer. I will try to contact them, the fact is that it just stuck on one of the first index files and never managed to update with the newer, even if upload the files and wipe the cache.

Comment: Are you sure you're uploading the files to the correct directory?

Comment: hey @Kerri, thank you, it was pointing issue (this is what a support guy told me) and now is finally fixed